# Where is cached information stored in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, caching

I am developing a website and I want to implement caching to improve its performance.

If I use

```
<@ OutputCache Duration="20" VaryByParam="None">
```

where will my page be stored? On the client side or on the server? If it's stored on the client side, where is it stored?

Can I cache a master page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify a location, the Output Cache directive will *at least* store it on the server. It also *allows* (via headers) intermediate proxies and clients to cache if they choose to.*

It's up to the consuming client to a) choose whether to respect the cache header and b) where to cache. For most browsers it's usually in "Temporary Internet Files" or some equivalent.

<sup>*It's more of a "suggestion" that proxies or clients cache, since either way it's ultimately up to them.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You may checkout the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx). According to it the default value of the cache location is Any which means:

> The output cache can be located on the
>   browser client (where the request
>   originated), on a proxy server (or any
>   other server) participating in the
>   request, or on the server where the
>   request was processed. This value
>   corresponds to the
>   HttpCacheability.Public enumeration
>   value

As far as caching the master you cannot put an OutputCache directive to a master page. You could do it programatically by enabling caching in all the content pages.